# Can't resolve method add ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have this code, and `add` is marked red with error:
`"Cannot resolve method 'add(java.util.ArrayList<com.example.InventoryItems>)'"`

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int lives;
    private int score;
    private int level;
    private Weapon weapon;
    private ArrayList<InventoryItems> inventoryItems;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lives = 3;
        this.score = 0;
        this.level = 1;
        inventoryItems = new ArrayList<InventoryItems>();
        setDefaultWeapon();
    }

    public void setDefaultWeapon() {
        this.weapon = new Weapon("Dagger", 3, WeaponType.Wooden);
    }

    public void setDefaultInventoryItems() {
        InventoryItems rubyNecklace = new InventoryItems("Ruby Necklace", ItemType.Amulet);
        rubyNecklace.add(inventoryItems);

    }
```

This is InventoryItems.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Pawel on 1/21/16.
 */

enum ItemType { Armor, Ring, Amulet, Junk, Weapon }

public class InventoryItems {
    private String name;
    private ItemType itemtype;

    public InventoryItems(String name, com.example.ItemType itemtype) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.itemtype = itemtype;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public com.example.ItemType getItemtype() {
        return itemtype;
    }

    public void setItemtype(com.example.ItemType itemtype) {
        this.itemtype = itemtype;
    }

}
```

Should I add the `add` method to InventoryItems? 
Why isn't it just possible to add `rubyNecklace` to `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you got it all mixed up. Change

```
rubyNecklace.add(inventoryItems);
```

to

```
inventoryItems.add(rubyNecklace);
```

`inventoryItems` is the `ArrayList`, & `rubyNecklace` is the item to be added.

Comment: Will accept answer in 12 minutes...thank you very much.